# Use case diagram for user account settings

Tags: uml

How can I represent the following situation in Use Case diagram:

> User can manage account settings:
>   change password, change language, date
>   of birth, etc.

I want to group "change password, change language, date of birth, etc." use cases  in the "manage account settings" use case. What relation should be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reality, Manage Account isn't a legit use case at all.

Use cases should *stand alone*.  In other words, the system should yield something of value to the actor if the use case in question was the *only* use case that the system provided.

"Manage Account" wouldn't stand alone. That is, no one would create a system that only allowed a user to manage their account.

But if you had to model the situation you described for homework purposes, it would probably look like this:

[alt text http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/5461/manageaccount2.png](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/5461/manageaccount2.png)

Comment: I wouldn't use inheritance in this case but rather include type relation.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a homework question. Wikipedia has [a nice description of how to use these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case_diagram). Note how each of the bubbles in the example refer to actions that actors take and their interactions. Use cases are almost entirely about user-facing information.

[image]

Comment: Look, I doubt about using the include relationship here or extend one.

Comment: the secret is that your separate use cases only have to relate to an Actor and not necessarily each other.

Answer (score 0):

Use Case Relations semantics can be sometimes fuzzy, it's up to you to be consistent. For example your case could be similar to this case:

[alt text http://askuml.com/files/2010/06/yuml-use-case-diagram03.png](http://askuml.com/files/2010/06/yuml-use-case-diagram03.png)

see http://askuml.com/blog/yuml-use-case/